# Cannot assign value of type 'JSON?' to type 'Float?'

Tags: ios, json, database, variable-assignment, algolia

I am fetching data from Algolia, which comes back as an array of `JSON` objects. I believe I am accessing a specific `Float` value from the `JSON` objects, but I still get the `Cannot assign value of type 'JSON?' to type 'Float?'` error when I try to assign that value to a Float variable.

When I print `print("responseHit printed: \(responseHit.object["displayCalories"] ?? 0.0)")`, this is the output:
[image]
These look like specific Float values to me.

But when I do not put the responseHit inside of a `"\()"` and try to assign it to a `Float` variable, I get the error:
[image]

**How can I get the values from the `JSON` object and assign them to a `Float` variable?**

Comment: "Looks like" - this is the key phrase. When you print an object, it is converted to a string via its debug description.  So, it "looks like" a float when printed, but it isn't. It is still a `JSON?` and Swift knows this.  How did you create this `JSON` object from the Algolia response?  Show relevant code (as a code block, not an image)